# Missing assembly errors when using "optimize code"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, release

I am struggling with this for two days now and can't find any solution on the internet.

Already tried to post this on the MS Forums, but this post is marked as spam, so I thought I try it here.

My app is working fine in debug mode when "optimizie code" is not checked and also in release mode. But when disabling the optimization, the checks before submitting to the store fail and I found some solutions that the optimization has to be checked.

This is the output:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Interner Compilerfehler
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.IClock' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Windows.SessionTelemetryModule'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.FixedSizeQueue`1' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.Storage'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule.CreateClient()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'TelemetryClient.set_Channel(ITelemetryChannel)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Clock' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'SessionTelemetryModule..ctor()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'SessionTelemetryModule..ctor()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'Clock.get_Instance()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'SessionTelemetryModule.GetPreviousSession(string, DateTimeOffset)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'IPlatform.GetApplicationSettings()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'SessionTelemetryModule.IsSessionActive(DateTimeOffset)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'IClock.get_Time()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'SessionTelemetryModule.SaveSessionState()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'IPlatform.GetApplicationSettings()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'SessionTelemetryModule.TrackSessionState()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'IClock.get_Time()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'UserContextInitializer.Initialize(ITelemetry)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'UserContext.set_AcquisitionDate(Nullable<DateTimeOffset>)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'UserContextInitializer.InitializeUserData()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'IPlatform.GetApplicationSettings()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'WindowsAppInitializer.Initalize()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'TelemetryConfiguration.get_ContextInitializers()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.SnapshottingDictionary`2' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'Storage..ctor(string)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'Storage..ctor(string)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'SnapshottingDictionary..ctor()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'Storage.Peek()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'FixedSizeQueue.Contains(string)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'Storage.Delete(StorageTransmission)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'FixedSizeQueue.Enqueue(string)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'PersistenceTransmitter.SendForDeveloperMode(ITelemetry, string)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'Transmission.SendAsync()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'Sender.Send(StorageTransmission, TimeSpan)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'Transmission.SendAsync()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.IContextInitializer' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.IClock' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Windows.SessionTelemetryModule'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.FixedSizeQueue`1' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.Storage'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule.CreateClient()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'TelemetryClient.set_Channel(ITelemetryChannel)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Clock' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'SessionTelemetryModule..ctor()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'SessionTelemetryModule..ctor()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'Clock.get_Instance()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'SessionTelemetryModule.GetPreviousSession(string, DateTimeOffset)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'IPlatform.GetApplicationSettings()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'SessionTelemetryModule.IsSessionActive(DateTimeOffset)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'IClock.get_Time()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'SessionTelemetryModule.SaveSessionState()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'IPlatform.GetApplicationSettings()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'SessionTelemetryModule.TrackSessionState()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'IClock.get_Time()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'UserContextInitializer.Initialize(ITelemetry)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'UserContext.set_AcquisitionDate(Nullable<DateTimeOffset>)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'UserContextInitializer.InitializeUserData()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'IPlatform.GetApplicationSettings()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'WindowsAppInitializer.Initalize()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'TelemetryConfiguration.get_ContextInitializers()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.SnapshottingDictionary`2' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in method 'Storage..ctor(string)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'Storage..ctor(string)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'SnapshottingDictionary..ctor()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'Storage.Peek()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'FixedSizeQueue.Contains(string)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'Storage.Delete(StorageTransmission)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'FixedSizeQueue.Enqueue(string)'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'PersistenceTransmitter.SendForDeveloperMode(ITelemetry, string)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'Transmission.SendAsync()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Method 'Sender.Send(StorageTransmission, TimeSpan)' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'Transmission.SendAsync()'. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.IContextInitializer' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in the application. There may have been a missing assembly.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(697,5): error : ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.3\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"C:\Users\tstark\source\repos\Christiani-Windows\Christiani\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\Christiani.rsp"' returned exit code 1
>   ========== Erstellen: 0 erfolgreich, 1 fehlerhaft, 0 aktuell, 0 übersprungen ==========
>   ========== Bereitstellen: 0 erfolgreich, 0 fehlerhaft, 0 übersprungen ==========

Visual Studio is the newest version and I tried to compile with target version 1803 and 1809.

Oh and I am on a new computer, of course the compilation worked on the old one.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks and Merry Christmas,

Thomas

Comment: If you create a new blank UWP project, could you compile it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Thanks Xavier, you pointed me to the right direction, tying to start from scratch with a simple project.
I removed the ApplicationInsights references and updated all other references which were deployed via nuget.
I can only guess, but it seems that the nuget references were broken when transfering the project to my new computer. But only when using optimization.
After that the project compiled without errors.